# Spacing issue in JLabel in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem related to spacing in labels.
there are four labels which are placed in a panel , 1st contain image while other contain plane text. I used Grid Layout because I want them in line by line but wanting no space between labels.
How I can do ...........?
help me.
This is code.!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnggr.png]

and I have the following result.!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRi60.png]

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a GridLayout because a GridLayout makes all components the same size so you get the spacing that you see.

You might try a `vertical BoxLayout`. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Or GridBagLayout or VerticalLayout from SwingLabs ;)

Comment: thanks buddy problem has been solved and one thing how I can set size of panel....?

Comment: @BroknnAngl, you don't need to set the size of the panel. You just use the `pack()` method of the JDialog and the dialog will be displayed at its preferred size which is based on the preferred size of all the components. You can always add an EmptyBorder to the panel to give it more space. The Swig tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Borders` that you can read for more information.

Comment: camickr please send me link again.

Comment: Follow the link given for `Using Layout Managers`. Then look at the table of contents, which the tutorial calls `Trail`. Then search for the section on borders.

Comment: @Camickr bro please tell me how i can set size of panel...>

Answer (score 0):

All cells in GridLayout have equal size. You have to use GridBagLayout  or SpringLayout  or BoxLayout .

Comment: how I can resize my JPanel...?

Comment: there is a method jpnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); it is an example

Comment: Don't use setPreferredSize(). This is not the was Swing was designed to be used. The Swing layout managers will determine the appropriate size.

Comment: brother he is just asking about resizing

Comment: i want ro resize my panel acoding to my size.
setPrefferredSize does not work

Comment: `i want ro resize my panel acoding to my size.` - You should NOT be hardcoding a size. What if you ever change the image to be a different size, or what if you ever change the font size of the label, then your hard coded size may not be appropriate. Let the layout managers do their job. They know better than you what the size should be on all platforms.

Comment: but there can be some situations where your want to keep your panel size hard coded, you are right in some cases but there are some cases where you have to keep it hard coded